# How to make Grid with rounded corners?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've seen other similar questions like [Add rounded corners to grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059400/add-rounded-corners-to-grid)
or [WPF. How to write rounded corners for Grid in the Grid Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914757/wpf-how-to-write-rounded-corners-for-grid-in-the-grid-style)

The answers are essentially

```
<Border CornerRadius="5">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

However I don't see it working.
My scenario is this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespece.MyCotrolType"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Background="Transparent"
             d:DesignHeight="106.24" d:DesignWidth="83.073">
    <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="15">
        <Grid Background="Black">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Background="Green">
                
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue">
                
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The above code produces two, green and blue rectangles.
What I want is simply the whole content of the border to be rounded/clipped.

I tried linked answers.

Comment: I'm just wondering... why my question is closed and marked as duplicate, and the other two I've linked in my question are not? And they don't even have the `How to make the contents of a round-cornered border be also round-cornered?` question linked, which also didn't fully answered the issue but actually pointed me in good direction so that I've made my own solution. Those other questions are the ones that I've found in search result and if my the were marked the same as mine, I would't even create this question... Makes no sense to me.